# Deleting a cell is not clearing UITextField inside of cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a custom cell that contains a UITextField. The problem is that when I try to delete a cell and then add a cell, the added cell's text field has the string from the cell that I had previously deleted. My second problem is that I have these cells visually number based on there index path, but if I rearrange them, the numbers do not change to their new places. I have tried to fix this by reloading the table, but then other problems arise. Any help on either of these problems would be very much appreciated. Here is the code I am using:

To delete(tried to clear the textfield):

```
Cell *cell = (Cell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textField.text = @"";

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: @[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
//[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

To set the visual numbering:

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSString *rowString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.", (int)indexPath.row + 1];
self.cell.rowNumber = rowString1;
```

In the cell:

```
- (void) setRowNumber:(NSString *)rowNumber{
    _rowNumber = rowNumber;
    self.periodLabel.text = _rowNumber;
}

self.periodLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.periodLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 6, 30, 30);
self.periodLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.periodLabel.text = self.rowNumber;
self.periodLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.periodLabel];
```

Comment: In your UITableViewCell subclass, Override prepareForReuse to clear all your contents.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCells are reused. This essentially means that each time you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier you may get the same cell that was previously provided to another row. This is a bit weird at first. The reason they do this is to avoid excessive object creation and memory allocation when the table has more rows.

Practically speaking, this means that you always need to set the values (i.e. label text, images, etc.) each time dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns a cell, otherwise the values will remain from a previous row.

More info here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW5